# What's the best way to send arrays, (containing a set of coordinates) to an arduino from a python script?

Tags: python

At the moment I'm working on a Michael Reevesesque servo set up, where I want to aim a laser connected to two servos in 3D space. At the moment I've got things working using a joystick and can aim using that, however i now want to control the aim of the servos using a python script (which will eventually be a GUI with a camera and use the mouse to aim). Meanwhile, I'd just like to send arrays to the Arduino to read and adjust the servo angles via the serial port, as instructed by a python script.

I'm guessing it will have to look something like this:

Python:

```
import serial

arduino = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)

while True:
        x = input()
        y = input()
        coordinates = [float(x), float(y)]
        arduino.write(coordinates)
```

Then ideally the arduino code would be as simple as reading the serial and saving the coordinates as a list or array like object and slicing appropriately to work out the angles for each servo.

Any suggestions?

Comment: To use the Arduino tag here, you must have Arduino code in your question.  Read the tag.  Vote to close until you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep
import serial
import struct
arduino = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600) 

while True:
     arduino.write(struct.pack('>BBB',1,2,3))
     print arduino.readline() 
     sleep(.5)
```

Or use it:
https://github.com/PowerBroker2/pySerialTransfer